# Spider Charts are not loading data while accessing our application in latest Chrome Browser, but loading in Microsoft edge browser

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

Spider Charts are not loading data while accessing our application in latest Chrome Browser(113.0.5672.93), but loading in Microsoft edge browser.
Previously the spider charts loads the data fine in chrome browser, but from 4 to 5 weeks we are facing this issue. I think this is due to the latest chrome browser update. We are not getting any error in the console while accessing the application.

We are using the following versions:
--> `chart.js: 2.9.3 --> ng2-charts: 2.3.0 --> Angular CLI: 13.1.2`
Please find the below screenshots and difference between the chrome browser and Microsoft Edge.

[Microsoft Edge Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAkYv.png)

[Chrome Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYjd9.png)

We tried to update the Chart.js and ng2-charts packages but no luck.